# Why my WebRTC connection works only at local network?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am experimenting with `WebRTC`, simply building chat on a `data channel`. I have a problem that the chat works when both peers are connected on the same local network. Where peers try to connect from different networks (I have been testing this with 2 computers one connected to my home Internet network and the other one via my phone wifi router).

The behavior of chat seems to be fine, `offer` and `answer` are sent correctly via signaling server. And with the same signaling server the `ice candidate` is sent as well.

```
peer.onicecandidate = (iceEvent: RTCPeerConnectionIceEvent) => {
  if (iceEvent.candidate) {
    const message: ConnectionEvent = {
      type: ConnectionEventType.CANDIDATE,
      caller: null,
      callee: event.caller,
      room: event.room,
      data: iceEvent.candidate,
    };

    ws.send(message);
  } else {
    // All ICE candidates have been sent
  }
};
```

So the peer that creates `offer` sends only *ONE* `ice candidate` and i think this is the problem becouse the peer creating `answer` sends *TWO* `ice candidates`.

What can be a problem here? When should i call `addIceCandidate` ?

This is example `console log` with *sent* and *recieved* data

Peer offering connection:

> sent: CONNECT Object {type: "CONNECT", caller: Object, callee: null,
>   room: Object, data: null}
>
> recieved: CONNECT Object {type: "CONNECT", caller: Object, callee:
>   null, room: Object, data: null}
>
> sent: OFFER Object {type: "OFFER", caller: Object, callee: Object,
>   room: Object, data: Object}
>
> sent: CANDIDATE Object {type: "CANDIDATE", caller: Object, callee:
>   Object, room: Object, data: Object}
>
> sent: CANDIDATE Object {type: "CANDIDATE", caller: Object, callee:
>   Object, room: Object, data: Object}
>
> recieved: ANSWER Object {type: "ANSWER", caller: Object, callee:
>   Object, room: Object, data: Object}
>
> recieved: CANDIDATE Object {type: "CANDIDATE", caller: Object, callee:
>   Object, room: Object, data: Object}

Peer creating answer:

> sent: CONNECT Object {type: "CONNECT", caller: Object, callee: null,
>   room: Object, data: null}
>
> recieved: OFFER Object {type: "OFFER", caller: Object, callee: Object,
>   room: Object, data: Object}
>
> recieved: CANDIDATE Object {type: "CANDIDATE", caller: Object, callee:
>   Object, room: Object, data: Object}
>
> recieved: CANDIDATE Object {type: "CANDIDATE", caller: Object, callee:
>   Object, room: Object, data: Object}
>
> sent: ANSWER Object {type: "ANSWER", caller: Object, callee: Object,
>   room: Object, data: Object}
>
> sent: CANDIDATE Object {type: "CANDIDATE", caller: Object, callee:
>   Object, room: Object, data: Object}

Comment: If you stringify the objects before logging them out it will probably be easier to find a clue to what is wrong, e.g. `console.log("sent:", JSON.stringify(data))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the answer provided above but STUN fails when symmetric natting comes across.

In order to have this worked seamlessly, You need to have TURN server in place, which works in symmetric natting as well.

The implementation remains same but it works on TCP protocol which implies it tracks every packet transmitted. The implementation is as follows:

```
var servers = { 'iceServers':[{ 'urls': 'turn:<turn-server-address>' }] };
connection = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
```

What this implantation does is it sends TCP encapsulated turn requests which are further resolved and sent across to the recipient.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [STUN](https://www.3cx.com/pbx/what-is-a-stun-server/) server for connect outside local network:

> A STUN (Session Traversal of User Datagram Protocol [UDP] Through
>   Network Address Translators [NATs]) server allows NAT clients (i.e. IP
>   Phones behind a firewall) to setup phone calls to a VoIP provider
>   hosted outside of the local network.

For example for Google STUN server:

```
var servers = { 'iceServers': [{ 'urls': 'stun:74.125.142.127:19302' }] };
//var  _iceServers = [{ url: 'stun:74.125.142.127:19302' }], // stun.l.google.com - Firefox does not support DNS names.

connection = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
```

You can look at [my code](https://github.com/alexan1/SignalRTC).

And web application itself: https://signalrtc.com/

Comment: @Vardius, do you use ip? sometimes it doesn't work with DNS

Comment: Ye i provide stun ip address

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how routers and or firewalls are set up, you might also need to configure both STUN and TURN.

See [Introduction to WebRTC protocols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Protocols) to understand the difference between STUN and TURN.